# How to specify min and max digits for a bank account number?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, types, constraints

Is it possible to constrain the number of digits allowed in a column of integer data type in PostgreSQL. I have the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE bank_accounts (    
    id              SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY
  , number_account  INTEGER(26)  NOT NULL
);
```

We can enter something like:

```
1 -- one digit
23 -- two digits
444 -- three digits
5555 -- four digits
```

Etc. ... up to 26 digits.

But I want to constrain my column to store *exactly* 26 digits, not less and not more. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bank account number is **not an integer** by nature. 26 decimal digits are too  much for [`integer` or `bigint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) anyway.

A bank account number is **not a numeric value** at all, really, even if we *could* use the type [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) for storage. It can handle 26 decimal digits easily. But it also allows fractional digits (and other decorators, [like @klin commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873492/how-to-specify-minimum-and-maximum-digits-on-column-of-integer-data-type-of-post#comment80695315_46874156)). You can restrict to `numeric(26)`, which is short for `numeric(26,0)`, to remove fractional digits from storage. But that still allows fractional digits on input, which are then rounded off. And other decorators. All of these seem undesirable for a bank account number:

```
SELECT numeric(26) '12345678901234567890123456'
     , numeric(26) '12345678901234567890123456.4'  -- rounded down
     , numeric(26) '12345678901234567890123456.5'  -- rounded up
     , numeric(26) '1e25'
     , numeric(26) '1.2345e25'
     , numeric(26) '+12345678901234567890123456.5'

SELECT numeric(26) '99999999999999999999999999.5'  -- error after rounding up
```

A bank account number is **more like text** by nature, so data type [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) seems more appropriate ([like @klin provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46874067/939860)), even if that occupies a bit more space on disk ([like @a_horse mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46874156/939860)). 27 bytes vs. 17 bytes for `numeric` - or 30 vs. 20 bytes in RAM. See:

- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)

However, you would not want to apply [**collation rules**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) to bank account numbers. That happens with collatable types like `text` or `varchar` if your DB cluster runs with a non-C locale. Would be a void effort for only digits to begin with. But you still get slower sorting and slower indexes etc. Notably, the ["abbreviated keys" feature](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#Sorting_optimization_.28Abbreviated_Keys.29) in Postgres 9.5 or later is currently (incl. Postgres 10) [disabled for non-C locales](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Abbreviated_keys_glibc_issue).

Putting everything together, I suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE bank_account (
   bank_account_id serial  PRIMARY KEY
-- bank_account_id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY  -- in Postgres 10+
 , number_account  text COLLATE "C" NOT NULL  -- disable collation rules
 , CONSTRAINT number_account_has_26_digits CHECK (number_account ~ '^\d{26}$')
);
```

Asides:

- Consider an `IDENTITY` column instead of the `serial` in in Postgres 10+. Details:

  - https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/
- <strike>`INTEGER(26)`</strike> is not valid syntax in Postgres, where the [**`integer`** data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) has no modifiers. You can chose from `int2`, `int4` (default `integer`) and `int8`, though - the dangling number signifying occupied bytes, not the number of digits allowed.

Comment: An anecdote to underscore "a bank account number is not an integer": my UK current account number starts with a `0`; consequently, I could not set up a direct debit to a particular charity, because their system truncated the input and then rejected it. Even if your current format mandates the first digit is in `[1-9]`, using a numeric type would be inviting future pain if the format ever changes.

Comment: Collate "C" really makes a difference. In my tests sorting a non-indexed 26-digit column on a larger table was approx. 3 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

[The maximum integer value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) is 2147483647, maximum bigint is 9223372036854775807. You cannot use integer types for the column.

It seems that the simplest way is to define the column as text with a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE bank_accounts (
    id serial primary key,
    number_account text not null check (number_account ~ '^\d{26}$')
);
```

The regular expression used in the check constraint means `a string with exactly 26 digits`.